# Why does Microsoft Word's "Protected View" prevent editing?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, editing

To the best of my understanding (and correct me if I'm wrong), the purpose of Protected View is to display the document without executing any macros that the document may contain, in case those macros are malicious. (Whether it makes sense for a "document" to potentially contain *auto-executing code* in the first place is a whole other matter.) So why does Protected View prevent editing? There doesn't seem to be any logical reason that not executing macros (if there even are any; as far as I can tell, this restriction seems to exist even for documents that don't actually contain any macros) should prevent editing the other contents of a document (or even *editing* the macros themselves, for that matter). What am I missing?

Comment: Protected View is a read-only mode, which acts like a sandbox, protecting files from potential threats from macros, viruses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft word codebase is vast, with a significant focus on backward compatibility; the protected view, however, is a much newer and smaller feature that can be focused entirely on allowing you to view a document safely.

Only enabling a minimal set of features makes it much easier for them to secure this environment. They will only be parsing a subset of the data inside the doc/docx file, making a considerably lower attack surface for common attack vectors against products like this.

For more detail, see [What is Protected View?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) - Microsoft Support

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adam, I added a link for you.

Comment: @AdamLark - I have retracted my flag, provided my own grammatical improvements, and retracted my downvote.

Comment: @AdamLark, chatgpt answers tend to be a bit generic, teachers pov and lack details, citations and credits. And they are on the rise. I  am afraid, I would have made the same assumption.  Plus oned it too